# Problem with table in matlab2tikz on Ubuntu

Tags: tikz-pgf, ubuntu, matlab2tikz

I have been using matlab2tikz last year on mac and it worked perfectly fine. Now I'm using it on Ubuntu and encounter some problems. FYI in installed texlive-full which does include pgf 2.1 and in my preamble I added \usepackage{tikz} and \usepackage{pgfplots}. When I compile my latex document (beamer class) in KILE I get following error message:

```
 `(./TIKZTest.tikz
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
&lt;to be read again&gt; 
                   \def 
l.25 };


! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H &lt;return&gt;  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.25 };


! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H &lt;return&gt;  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.25 };

! Missing control sequence inserted.
&lt;inserted text&gt; 
                \inaccessible 
l.25 };


! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H &lt;return&gt;  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.25 };


! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H &lt;return&gt;  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.25 };

! Undefined control sequence.
&lt;recently read&gt; \pgfplotstable@loc@TMPa 

l.25 };


! Package pgfplots Error: The requested list entry with index 0 of \pgfplots@ta
ble is too large; this list has not enough elements..

See the pgfplots package documentation for explanation.
Type  H &lt;return&gt;  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.25 };


! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, could not retrieve column '' from table '\\pgf
plots@table@@table@name '. Please check spelling (or introduce name aliases)..

See the pgfplots package documentation for explanation.
Type  H &lt;return&gt;  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.25 };


! Package pgfplots Error: The requested list entry with index 1 of \pgfplots@ta
ble is too large; this list has not enough elements..

See the pgfplots package documentation for explanation.
Type  H &lt;return&gt;  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.25 };


! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, could not retrieve column '' from table '\\pgf
plots@table@@table@name '. Please check spelling (or introduce name aliases)..

See the pgfplots package documentation for explanation.
Type  H &lt;return&gt;  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.25 };

! Package pgfplots Warning: the current plot has no coordinates (left?)

! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/legend cell align' and I 
am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H &lt;return&gt;  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.28 \end{axis}

) <use Queenslscapelogocmyk-eps-converted-to.pdf>
<use Aqua-spot-rgb-clear10025.jpg> <use TUHHLogo-eps-converted-to.pdf> [10]
(./GroupSemPres.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
(Font)              up to 1.0pt have occurred.


LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
)`
```

It does show the coordinate system and legend, but doesn't plot any data. I just now discovered that it does plot something when I give the data as coordinates and not as a table. Might there be a general problem with the table in tikz on linux or am I missing something. Otherwise I would have to convert the whole tikz file matlab2tikz gives me to a coordinates list.

Here is the tikz-file I get from matlab2tikz (I deleted some data to make it shorter):

```
    % This file was created by matlab2tikz v0.4.7 running on MATLAB 8.1.
% Copyright (c) 2008--2014, Nico Schlömer <nico.schloemer@gmail.com>
% All rights reserved.
% Minimal pgfplots version: 1.3
% 
% The latest updates can be retrieved from
%   http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz
% where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
% 
\begin{tikzpicture}  

\begin{axis}[%  
width=5cm,  
height=4cm,  
scale only axis,  
xmin=0,  
xmax=0.018,  
ymin=0.00015,  
ymax=0.0005,  
legend style={draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left}  
]  
\addplot [color=blue,solid]  
  table[row sep=crcr]{0 0.000311697265625003\\  
0.001953125 0.000321697265625003\\  
};  
\addlegendentry{wp1Exp};  

\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 12.04? I had to install a more recent version of TeXLive on my 12.04 machine. The standard version of TeXLive in 12.04 is TeXLive-2009.

Comment: Yes I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and you're right, its tex live 2009. I'll try to get a newer one than. Did it solve the problem for you?

Comment: After installing a more recent version of TeXLive (I believe it was 2012), I was/am able to use matlab2tikz without any further problems, save the one problem that exists between screen and chair.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue fixed by updating to the latest release.